# In core data: why does arraycontroller view doesn't notice changes in object.otherobject.property but only object.property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nscollectionview

I have an nsarraycontroller * ctrlr1 fetching its data from core data entity obj1 witch has a relationship one to one to obj2 also fetched by nsarraycontroller * ctrlr2
in ctrlr i have set via IB a fetch predicate like this

```
inactive == 0 && obj2.active ==1
```

I have a view with bound properties for obj1 attributes and if i click the checkbox bound to inactive my nscollection view correctly fades obj1 and its view BUT
If in another nscollectionview I change obj2 attribute active to be 0, the first nscollectionview doesn't get updated istantly even if I force a `fetch:` method, what could it be? fetch works perfectly on first fetch (app launch)

Answer (score 0):

The `NSArrayController` doesn't know that it needs to observe a potentially arbitrarily deep tree of objects, and just observes properties on the objects in the observed array (and the array itself). So you'd need to provide a change notification programatically for a "deep" change to bubble up to the array controller, or explicitly tell the controller to observe those deep key paths.

Comment: so should i post [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self        selector:@selector(???)           name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification          object:managedObjectContext]; to nsarraycontroller? how can i use other method? tnx